# Naming file created by ResourceResponseEntity

Tags: java, naming

In my REST application I've got a request which is returning an excel file to a user via
`return new ResourceResponseEntity(new ByteArrayResource(content)` where `content` is `byte[]`

### The problem

The problem is the result file is always named the same way that the request method name, which is bad because it would be hard to locate some information in that files

### Question

So the question is can I somehow control the file naming process using what I am using right now, any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might create a `HttpHeaders` object with a `Content-Disposition` header with

```
HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
header.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + filename;
```

and then add this `HttpHeaders` object to your ResourceResponseEntity with something like `.headers(header)`.